# Python rfft algorithm

Tags: python-3.x

Numpy has a `rfft` function to compute FFT or Real input. I would like to code my own code for that. Here's my actual code of DFT and FFT [[ref](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/28/understanding-the-fft/)].

```py
def DFT_slow(x):
    """Compute the discrete Fourier Transform of the 1D array x"""
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=float)
    N = x.shape[0]
    n = np.arange(N)
    k = n.reshape((N, 1))
    M = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k * n / N)
    return np.dot(M, x)
```

```py
def FFT(x):
    """A recursive implementation of the 1D Cooley-Tukey FFT"""
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=float)
    N = x.shape[0]

    if N % 2 > 0:
        raise ValueError("size of x must be a power of 2")
    elif N <= 32:  # this cutoff should be optimized
        return DFT_slow(x)
    else:
        X_even = FFT(x[::2])
        X_odd = FFT(x[1::2])
        factor = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * np.arange(N) / N)
        return np.concatenate([X_even + factor[:N / 2] * X_odd,
                               X_even + factor[N / 2:] * X_odd])
```

I don't know much about Fourier transform, any idea how I would compute the `rfft` from these codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rfft` is just the positive-frequency components of the full `fft` of the input, since the `fft` of a real-valued signal is conjugate-symmetric in frequency.

```
def rDFT_slow(x):
    """Compute the discrete Fourier Transform of the 1D array of real data x"""
    x = np.real(np.asarray(x, dtype=float))
    N = x.shape[0]
    n = np.arange(N)
    k = np.arange(N//2+1).reshape((N//2+1,1))
    M = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k * n / N)
    return np.dot(M, x)
```

There are some trickier factors that go into implementing the recursive version when you're only calculating half of the coefficients, but the slow `rDFT` should get you started.

Comment: How can I compute the inverse of such a transform? I tried to use a pseudo inverse but the result is not very good...

Comment: @Dave If you want to do it without using `np.fft.irfft`, you can reconstruct the signal using `N//2+1` sinusoids with amplitudes and phases proportional to the transform components. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726152/12482432) for more details - the second implementation only uses `rfft` coefficients.

Comment: Thank you, very helpfull. Thanks to your code I made a good `ifft` function. But I have trouble to compute the `irfft`. I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZYDP7R9e) but it returns a sine twice as big as the original. Can you help me?

Comment: @Dave When you calculate the individual sinusoids, you should divide by `len(x)` (the length of the reconstructed signal), not `N` (the length of the `rfft`).

Comment: @Dave Also, you should be careful: if the original `len(x)` is odd, `2*(N-1) != len(x)`. Instead, `2*(N-1) == len(x)-1`. You can fix this by checking if `X[-1].real == X[-1]`. If it does, the original `len(x)` was `2*(N-1)` because `len(x)` was even. If it doesn't, the original `len(x)` was `2*N-1` because `len(x)` was odd.